# How can I integrate Chrome Password Manager and Mac Keychain on Mac

Tags: google-chrome, keychain

When Chrome saves my user/password combo for a website, is there a way to have this sync into Mac Keychain as well?

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to sync them; they don't trust each other.
I don't see it as likely what you want will ever happen. It's too 'unsafe'.

Apple released an [iCloud Password Extension for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/icloud-passwords/pejdijmoenmkgeppbflobdenhhabjlaj?hl=en) but a) it's Windows only [Apple want you to use Safari on Mac, not Chrome] & b) enabling one disables the other; they won't work together.